# Any good tutorials to help me to create header files for randomizing in C, C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to create a header file for C, C++ which is specific to help in randomization.

Comment: Please elabroate your problem. How would a header file help you solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question.

If you can, you might find it helpful to read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I get the impression that English is not this person's first language so those that are downvoting his question may want to cut him (or her) a little bit of slack.

Comment: @kasperasky: please can you clarify your question.  You don't provide enough information for us to understand what you are asking, and the impatient downvote you when that happens.

Answer (score 3):

Header files are C files, except that they *shouldn't* contain any code implementation (only declarations).

For example, suppose the C file "dummy.c":

```
int dummy_function(int x){
   return x+1;
}
```

A good C header file would be:

```
#ifndef _DUMMY_HEADER_H_
#define _DUMMY_HEADER_H_ //This helps solve some possible errors

int dummy_function(int x);

#endif
```

If you use structures as arguments (or return values), you should put their declaration in the header.

```
typedef struct { int value; } myStruct;
int dummy_function(myStruct* x){
   return (*x).value+1;
}
```

Instead, you should write

```
#include "dummy.h"
int dummy_function(myStruct* x){
   return (*x).value+1;
}
```

And create the following header file:

```
#ifndef _DUMMY_HEADER_H_
#define _DUMMY_HEADER_H_

typedef struct{ int value; } myStruct;
int dummy_function(myStruct* x);

#endif
```

A good header file should be valid by itself (include all the '#include' statements it needs).

So, if your code is the implementation of a "double myRandom()" function, you should write this header file:

```
#ifndef _HEADER_NAME_
#define _HEADER_NAME_

double myRandom(void);  /* Can omit void in C++, but not in C */

#endif
```

If this isn't your problem, then please specify better.

Comment: I use extern on function declarations (as well as data declarations), primarily for consistency between the two.  Then, anything that is not a typedef (or enum type definition) or an extern declaration is suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure that I understand your question (I posted a comment to your question), but an answer might be this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* required for rand() and srand() */
```

This is the answer if you want to invoke the rand() and srand() functions, which are part of the C standard library. For example, see http://www.google.com/search?q=srand

Comment: Neither random() nor randomize() is part of the standard C library in C89 or C99.  The standard functions are rand() and srand().

Comment: Thanks: I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread1769.html, kasperasky, and see if it helps you to answer your question--or at least ask a little more specific question.